# Query (HTTP GET) data in Power Apps Portal from Web API with JavaScript

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, dynamics-365, dataverse, powerapps-portal

I have a "Starter Portal" Power App Portal.  I would like to utilize JavaScript and the Web API for querying data.  [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/web-api-overview) states

> You can use the Web API to perform create, update, and delete operations across all Microsoft Dataverse tables from your portal pages.

Further [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/web-api-perform-operations) only lists the CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE operations, and this API being accessible as

```
[Portal URI]/_api
```

And I have found how to successfully authenticate using a helper method to get a token for the header:

```
shell.getTokenDeferred().done(function (token) { ...}
```

This allows authentication as the  user logged into the portal so I believe all relevant Table Permissions, etc. are applied.

But, I would like to **retrieve** data (HTTP GET).  I know this is [possible from the Dataverse Web API.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-data-web-api). This api is exposed as

```
[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/
```

Are these really the same API, just exposed a different way for the portal? Is it possible to use the GET endpoints or the second API altogether, authenticated as a Portal Contact user like the previous operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same API but permissions are different, you will need to enable the tables you want to access inside the *_api* endpoint.

You can read more info at this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/read-operations, there is also an XrmToolBox tool to assist you in this operation (but I didn't try it) https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/PowerPortalWebAPIHelper/

Regarding the Web API calls, I released a new tool to create them (similar to CRM REST Builder) I also added a "Portals" syntax (is in preview) but the generated urls are the same. Link: https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB

Comment: Ok that read-operations doc is half of the puzzle!  Can I query the Dataverse WEB API as a portal user, outside of the Portal? Say I wanted to write my own portal app?  We could set the authorization up as a cloud identity provider - Azure AD B2C, for ex.

Comment: not aware of a way to run execute the Dataverse Web API as a portal user outside a Portal. But if you are outside a portal you can use the standard Web API endpoint, the only thing is that you will need to implement the security model to replicate what a Portal user (a contact for example) can do or not.